# Having trouble to understand how to use global variables in python

Tags: python, algorithm, global-variables

So this is a Codewars Problem I am trying to solve and basically I learnt whatever python I know via doing this site. So I tried to do constraint programming in this problem. I think I am in the right direction but 'count' doesn't seem to do it's job i.e count _-.-_/ It would really help if you can guide me to proper direction. Thanks!

**problem** You are given a certain array of positive and negative integers which elements occur only once (all of them different from 0), a certain number known as target, t, t ≠ 0, and a number k, k > 0.

You should find the amount of combinations, which numbers are not contiguous elements of the given array and which sums (adding up their numbers) are in the range [t - k, t + k]

My code:

```
count=0    
def check_sum(arr,lb,ub,vlb,vub,add,wh):
    global count
    if(vlb>vub):
        return
    if wh==1:
        val=arr[vub]
        vub-=1
    else:
        val=arr[vlb]
        vlb+=1
    if add+val>ub:
        if add+val+arr[vlb]<ub:
            check_sum(arr,lb,ub,vlb,vub,add,0)
    elif add+val<lb:
        if add+val+arr[vub]>lb:
            check_sum(arr,lb,ub,vlb,vub,add,1)
    else:
        count+=1
        check_sum(arr,lb,ub,vlb,vub,add,1)
        check_sum(arr,lb,ub,vlb,vub,add,0)




def find_comb_noncontig(arr, t, k):
    # your code here
    arr.sort()

    check_sum(arr,t-k,t+k,0,len(arr)-1,0,1)
    check_sum(arr,t-k,t+k,0,len(arr)-1,0,0)

    return count
```

There is some problem in this code which I dont seem to understand regarding 'count'

Comment: What is your **specific** problem?

Comment: if i dry run the code it seems to update count. but for all test cases count shows 2.